# Select the elements at even indexes in maxima

Tags: maxima

In maxima, "sublist" allows you to select certain elements of a list with different criterions. I'd like to select the elements at even indexes. I've thought about something like

`sublist([1,2,4,5,7,8],evenp(sublist_indices()));`

but obviously it doesn't work. How can I do it without writing down a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, how about something like:

```
(%i2) L : [a, b, c, d, e, f, g];
(%o2)                        [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
(%i3) makelist (L[2*i], i, 1, floor (length(L) / 2));
(%o3)                              [b, d, f]
```